# What is causing this pattern of horizontal and vertical lines in my pictures?

Tags: canon, dslr, raw, banding

[image: Picture with lines]

I took pictures with a camera I have not used in years. The pictures appear to have vertical and horizontal pixel lines throughout. What is the cause and how can I remove them? I have no photo editing experience but downloaded Topaz DeNoise and that is not helping. Can I save these pictures and what is the issue with my camera? It's a Canon EOS T3. These are my Thanksgiving family pictures and I would love to save them.

Comment: is this a 100% view of the photo? what format (CR2, JPG) is the photo, which software do you use for viewing the photo?

Comment: This picture is cropped but these lines appear over the entire picture. It is in JPEG

Comment: What are your settings for the stored resolution? Could it be that you save as ‘JPG small’, which makes this the to-be-expected result quality?

Comment: I double checked and see that my picture is saved with a Cr2 extension. Is that my issue? Can I change it so that I can correct these lines? Thanks in advance for your reply. I appreciate your time.

Comment: Is there a filter on the lens? Also could you provide more detials on the image. Is this a screencap from a piece of software?

Answer (score 2):

You note that the pictures are CR2 images. These are Canon RAW files — they are not, in that state, usable for sharing and printing and so on. You need software to convert them. The most popular such software is Adobe Lightroom, but you can also download [Canon Digital Photo Professional](https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/software/digital-photo-professional.aspx?os=LINUX&language=EN) for free — or use open source software like [Rawtherapee](http://rawtherapee.com/).

The key thing here is that the pattern in your picture looks very, very much like an artifact from demosaicing ­— part of the process of converting the sensor data stored in the RAW CR2 image into final, viewable one. **Whatever software you're using to look at these images is doing it wrong.** Get Canon DPP or Rawtherapee and use that to convert to JPEG, and there should be no problem.